# Is there a browser for OSX that allows silent printing?

Tags: javascript, macos, browser, printing

For an in browser cash desk system we want to build, we are exploring the limits of browsers on OSX. At this point we can't find out if it's possible to print 'silent' from a browser on OSX.

Is it possible (for example by javascript) to give the browser a command to print without asking for confirmation?

- Google Chrome has a Kiosk Printing mode, but this only seems to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox allows silent printing.

Type in the address bar "about:config"

Right Click, add a new boolean property.

Use the name: print.always_print_silent
And value: true

You are good to go.